# Requisição Ajax com Laravel 5.4

Tags: ajax, laravel

Estou tentando realizar um exemplo de requisição `Ajax` com o `Laravel 5.4`.

O exemplo para teste é simples, apenas informar um valor numérico em um campo `input=text` na minha `View` e sai do campo para enviar para o `Controller`, então é somado + 10 para esse valor e então retorna esse valor para minha View para que possa ser exibido em um alert.

**HTML** : viewteste.blade.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="">      
            Valor: <input type="text" id="valor" name="valor" />
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

**JS** : o arquivo js está dentro do viewteste.blade.php, só separei para ficar mais fácil a interpretação.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
       $("#valor").on('blur', function()
       {
           valor = $(this).val();

           var token = $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content');
            $.ajax({

                type:'POST',
                url:"{!! URL::to('/teste/valor') !!}",
                dataType: 'JSON',
                data: {
                    "valor": 'POST',
                },
                success:function(data){
                    // Caso ocorra sucesso, como faço para pegar o valor
                    // que foi retornado pelo controller?
                    alert('Sucesso');
                },
                error:function(){
                  alert('Erro');
                },
            });


       });
    });
</script>
```

**Route**

```
Route::get('/teste',      'TesteAjaxController@index');
Route::post('/teste/valor', 'TesteAjaxController@valor');
```

**Controller**

```
class TesteAjaxController extends Controller
{
     public function index()
    {
        return view('painel.viewteste');
    }

    public function cep(Request $request)
    {
        $valor= $request->input('valor');
        $valor += 10;
        return $valor; // Como faço para retornar em json? em caso de mensagem de erros?

    }
}
```

*Observação*: Quando eu saiu do campo e coloco um alert de teste na função do js só para ver se está funcionando ele vai ... e consigo exibir o valor o problema é no envio do ajax mesmo.
Eu entro no /teste e carrega minha view, e quando eu coloco /teste/valor não exibe nada, aparece um erro:

```
Whoops, looks like something went wrong.
(1/1) MethodNotAllowedHttpException
```

Comment: apareço o erro porque o método é para requisição POST e não para GET ai da essa mensagem de método não aceito.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O erro aparece, porque, foi configurado a rota só para aceitar o verbo `POST` e isso vai funcionar com sua função em [ajax](/questions/tagged/ajax), pois, de cara a sua configuração está para o verbo `POST` igual configurado na sua rota.

Se quiser que esse método funcione também com outros `verbos` configure da seguinte forma o arquivo de rota:

```
Route::match(['get', 'post'], '/teste/valor', 'TesteAjaxController@valor');
```

com isso os dois tipos de `verbo` (`post` e `get`) vão funcionar.

e tem também a forma de liberar todos os `verbos`:

```
Route::any('/teste/valor', 'TesteAjaxController@valor');
```

***Nota:*** o correto é ter uma rota e um `verbo` configurado para cada endereço, ou seja, só criar outra configuração de rota e que esteja configurado para aquele `controller` e `método`, mas, no [framework](/questions/tagged/framework) [laravel](/questions/tagged/laravel) existe a opção de configurar como foi mencionado logo acima.

---

Na parte do [ajax](/questions/tagged/ajax) precisa colocar essa configuração:

```
<script>
    $.ajaxSetup({
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        }
    });

    $(document).ready(function(){
       $("#valor").on('blur', function()
       {
            valor = $(this).val();    
            $.ajax({

                type:'POST',
                url:"{!! URL::to('/teste/valor') !!}",
                dataType: 'JSON',
                data: {
                    "valor": valor
                },
                success:function(data){
                    // Caso ocorra sucesso, como faço para pegar o valor
                    // que foi retornado pelo controller?
                    alert('Sucesso');
                },
                error:function(){
                  alert('Erro');
                },
            });


       });
    });
</script>
```

<sub>***Referencias***</sub>

- [Routing](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/routing)
- [Basic Routing](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/routing#basic-routing)

Comment: Entendi o porquê não funciona quando eu coloco o método post direto no navegador ... Mas devo estar fazendo algo errado com relação ao envio do Ajax porque minha requisicao não chega até meu Controller

Comment: @BrunoAparecidodaSilva fiz uma edição.

Comment: Estou aqui tentando e ainda não funcionou, porém com a sua ajuda com o método ajax agora ele me retorna erro. deixei a seguinte rota `Route::post('/teste/valor', 'TesteAjaxController@valor');` e alterei a url do ajax para url:'/teste/valor'. Isso deveria funcionar?

Comment: Para fácilitar criei uma var com o nome de caminhourl = 'http://localhost/Projetos/ProjetoAjax/public/teste/valor' e faço a url receber esse valor e ainda assim continua dando erro

Comment: Qual o erro? @BrunoAparecidodaSilva com certeza já está chegando a requisição

Comment: O erro era o nome do meu token que estava com o nome incorreto! Obrigado pela ajuda !